# How To Pull Private Instagram Account's Feed via Instafeed.js?

Tags: javascript, html, instagram, instafeedjs

I am using instafeed.js to pull an Instagram account's feed onto my website. Currently it is just pulling my public account for development reasons. Everything works great for me there, the issue is that my client has a private account. Is there a way to pull their feed for their website even though it is private? I would think you would have to just get some sort of acceptance.

Here is my current code for it has any value to you.

```
      var feed = new Instafeed({
          get: 'user',
          userId: *******,
          accessToken: '{access_token}',
          template: '<div class="col-6"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></div>',
          resolution: 'standard_resolution'
        });
        feed.run();
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Adam, it was really late when I wrote that

Answer (score 0):

You either need that private account to authrorize your app and pull the recent photo using the access_token for that account. Or Follow the private account with the account for which you already have an access_token, but bare in mind the follow also has to be authroized.